# Subset one array column with another (boolean) array column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe like this (in Pyspark 2.3.1):

```python
from pyspark.sql import Row

my_data = spark.createDataFrame([
  Row(a=[9, 3, 4], b=['a', 'b', 'c'], mask=[True, False, False]),
  Row(a=[7, 2, 6, 4], b=['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'], mask=[True, False, True, False])
])
my_data.show(truncate=False)
#+------------+------------+--------------------------+
#|a           |b           |mask                      |
#+------------+------------+--------------------------+
#|[9, 3, 4]   |[a, b, c]   |[true, false, false]      |
#|[7, 2, 6, 4]|[w, x, y, z]|[true, false, true, false]|
#+------------+------------+--------------------------+
```

Now I'd like to use the `mask` column in order to subset the `a` and `b` columns:

```python
my_desired_output = spark.createDataFrame([
  Row(a=[9], b=['a']),
  Row(a=[7, 6], b=['w', 'y'])
])
my_desired_output.show(truncate=False)
#+------+------+
#|a     |b     |
#+------+------+
#|[9]   |[a]   |
#|[7, 6]|[w, y]|
#+------+------+
```

What's the "idiomatic" way to achieve this? The current solution I have involves `map`-ing over the underlying RDD and subsetting with Numpy, which seems inelegant:

```python
import numpy as np

def subset_with_mask(row):
    mask = np.asarray(row.mask)
    a_masked = np.asarray(row.a)[mask].tolist()
    b_masked = np.asarray(row.b)[mask].tolist()
    return Row(a=a_masked, b=b_masked)

my_desired_output = spark.createDataFrame(my_data.rdd.map(subset_with_mask))
```

Is this the best way to go, or is there something better (less verbose and/or more efficient) I can do using Spark SQL tools?

Comment: Depending on your pyspark version, you may be able to achieve this using [`arrays_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#arrays_zip) and [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter) or with a pandas `udf`.

Comment: @pault it looks like `filter` isn't available in my version of PySpark (2.3.1) but an answer using/demonstrating those functions might be informative all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a UDF, which you can optionally specialize by the data type in the array:

```python
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

def _mask_list(lst, mask):
    return np.asarray(lst)[mask].tolist()

mask_array_int = F.udf(_mask_list, T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType()))
mask_array_str = F.udf(_mask_list, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))

my_desired_output = my_data
my_desired_output = my_desired_output.withColumn(
    'a', mask_array_int(F.col('a'), F.col('mask'))
)
my_desired_output = my_desired_output.withColumn(
    'b', mask_array_str(F.col('b'), F.col('mask'))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

UDFs mentioned in the previous answer is probably the way to go prior to the array functions added in Spark 2.4. For the sake of completeness, here is a "pure SQL" implementation before 2.4.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = my_data.withColumn("row", monotonically_increasing_id())

df1 = df.select("row", posexplode("a").alias("pos", "a"))
df2 = df.select("row", posexplode("b").alias("pos", "b"))
df3 = df.select("row", posexplode("mask").alias("pos", "mask"))

df1\
    .join(df2, ["row", "pos"])\
    .join(df3, ["row", "pos"])\
    .filter("mask")\
    .groupBy("row")\
    .agg(collect_list("a").alias("a"), collect_list("b").alias("b"))\
    .select("a", "b")\
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+------+------+
|     a|     b|
+------+------+
|[7, 6]|[w, y]|
|   [9]|   [a]|
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is to use `pyspark.sql.functions.expr`, [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter), and [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform):

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import (
    functions as F,
    SparkSession
)

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[4]').getOrCreate()

bool_df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [True]*4 + [False]],
    ['b', [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [False, True, False, True, False]]
], columns=['id', 'int_arr', 'bool_arr'])
bool_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(bool_df)

def filter_with_mask(in_col, mask_col, out_name="masked_arr"):
    filt_input = f'arrays_zip({in_col}, {mask_col})'
    filt_func = f'x -> x.{mask_col}'
    trans_func = f'x -> x.{in_col}'
    
    result = F.expr(f'''transform(
        filter({filt_input}, {filt_func}), {trans_func}
    )''').alias
    return result
```

Using the function:

```py
bool_sdf.select(
    '*', filter_with_mask('int_arr', 'bool_arr', bool_sdf)
).toPandas()
```

Results in:

```
id         int_arr                          bool_arr   masked_arr
 a [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]   [True, True, True, True, False] [0, 1, 2, 3]
 b [5, 6, 7, 8, 9] [False, True, False, True, False]       [6, 8]
```

This should be possible with `pyspark >= 2.4.0` and `python >= 3.6`.